# HTML Generated image link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm a web designer and i'm currently designing a website that includes images. I was wonder if anyone can tell me what it is called or if you can guide me the right way so i can do some research on my own and learn it.

Basically what i need to know is how can you lets say if the user click on the image it will bring them to another html with that image plus that image information

A current example... [wallhaven.cc](https://alpha.wallhaven.cc/) if you go there and if you click a wall paper.. every wallpaper has a specific link. is that generated or does that mean that literally EVERY image on that website has a web page of its own?

Comment: There is good resource for you named [w3school.com](http://www.w3schools.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do it both ways you can use what is called dynamically generated web pages or you can create each page manually.

So if you were to go with the dynamically generated web pages you would probably want to consider looking around a JavaScript Template Engine. I currently am using this one while I build my own. http://idangero.us/template7/. That is the best JavaScript Template Engine you can get. Plus it is free and Open-Source. But if you go with creating each page manually you will have a lot of work on you hand! So personally I would choose using the JavaScript Template Engine!

Have a great day.

Joseph Shenton
http://timedevs.net/

Answer (score 0):

There is one page for image details, the number at the end of the link is the image id, which tells the server which data to output.